# Lime Survey Equation

Tags: mysql, equation, limesurvey

In Lime Survey, I want to get a sum total of subquestion values in an array question.

I used the following:

{(A1_sq1.value+A1_sq2.value+A1_sq3.value+A1_sq4.value+A1_sq5.value+A1_sq6.value+A1_sq7.value+A1_sq8.value+A1_sq9.value+A1_sq10.value+A1_sq11.value)}

If I click the array radio buttons in order, I get the correct total. But if I check on them out of order, I get each individual response listed in sequence (i.e. no sum).

So clicking in order I might get '18', whereas, if I did the whole set backwards, I'd get '12221222112'

Is this a bug, or am I writing the equation wrong?

Comment: https://www.limesurvey.org/en/forum/design-issues/100307-equation-issue#120270

Answer (score 2):

If the question code for the array is "A1", this will return the total value for the array:

`{sum(that.A1.value)}`